# how to resolve "Error: No module named 'airflow.www'" while starting airflow websever

Tags: airflow

Getting below error while starting Airflow webserver

balajee@Balajees-MacBook-Air.local:~$ airflow webserver -p 8080
[2018-12-03 00:29:37,066] {**init**.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor

[2018-12-03 00:29:38,776] {models.py:271} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/balajee/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120

## Logfiles: - -

Error: No module named 'airflow.www'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you would like to improve your chances of getting an answer please visit our help page: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 10):

Fixed for me

```
pip3 uninstall -y gunicorn
pip3 install gunicorn==19.4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem this morning, and I found a strange solution, may it helps you. I think maybe you just **need to change the command running directory**.
I install `airflow` basic dependence in my `virtualenv` directory `venv` with PyCharm help, and I use PyCharm build-in `Terminal` tab to directly access my `venv`, and I use `airflow initdb` to init sqlite database to store all my logs and ops, then according to the official tutorial I use `airflow webserver` to start the webserver. But somehow today I use my Mac terminal, and start virtulenv, and start airflow webserver, and I encounter this problem with:

```
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================            

Error: No module named 'airflow.www'
[2019-05-26 07:45:27,130] {cli.py:833} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
[2019-05-26 07:45:27,130] {cli.py:834} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

And I tried @Evgeniy Sobolev's solution by reinstall `gunicorn` and nothing changed, but when I still using my PyCharm Terminal, it can still running successfully. I guess maybe it is because the **`first directory`** you init your db and running webserver is critical. By default when I use PyCharm Terminal to init db and start webserver is the `Project root directory`, like:

```
(venv) root@root:~/GitHub/FakeProject$ airflow webserver
```

But today I check into `venv` to start virtualenv, and **the root directory changed!**

```
root@root:~/GitHub/FakeProject/SubDir$ source venv/bin/activate 
(venv) root@root:~/GitHub/FakeProject/SubDir$ airflow webserver
** Error **
```

So in this way it encounters `Error: No module named 'airflow.www'`, so I check out the directory, and the webserver running successfully just like PyCharm Terminal:

```
(venv) root@root:~/GitHub/FakeProject/SubDir$ cd ..
(venv) root@root:~/GitHub/FakeProject$ airflow webserver
** It works **
```

I thought maybe airflow store some metadata (like setup a PATH, maybe) in the first time init your airflow db, so you can not change your command running directory.
I hope it may help somebody in the future. **Just check your directory!**

Comment: I activated the database in /mydir/airflow, and got OP's error when in /mydir. Stepping into /mydir/airflow resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem with gunicorn.
Try to execute this two commands:

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall -y gunicorn
sudo -H pip3 install gunicorn
```

It should resolve your problem, cause airflow show you not clear error message related to gunicorn problems

Answer (score 1):

I did this steps for the problem happens:

1. create a separate virtualenv only for airflow (I use anaconda distribution)
2. activate this env with `conda activate`
3. install airflow: `pip install apache-airflow`
4. at this moment the error `No module named 'airflow.www'` was showed for me

To fix follow this steps:

1. Look for where is your gunicorn in: `whereis gunicorn`
2. gunicorn have to stay only in your virtualenv directory: `/home/yourname/anaconda3/envs/airflow_env/bin/gunicorn`
3. If it stay in two directories, let it just in your airflow enviroment. Remove it all from another.

Another way to verify if gunicorn is in another directories is printing your PATH variable: `echo $PATH`. Look for gunicorn in `/home/yourname/.local/bin` and another anaconda directories from PATH. Remove all references. Remove gunicorn from conda base env as well: `pip uninstall gunicorn`.

With this steps, I think your problem will be solved.

I used anaconda distribution, but I think the same process can be done without it. I used airflow 1.10.0 and python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a custom home directory for airflow other than default one (`~/airflow`) during the installation:

1. You need first export the custom path:

```sh
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/your/custom/path/airflow
```

2. Go to the airflow directory and then Run the webserver

```sh
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

3. Run scheduler too

```sh
airflow scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if gunicorn is installed already in server. for me it was installed in /usr/local/bin and it was taking precedence over gunicorn version installed with airflow. uninstall earlier one or fix $PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by starting the webserver from the airflow folder itself.

I was previously trying to open the server from the home directory but the required modules could not be found which may be the case here.

Late to the party but could help others who get here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue using latest airflow version 2.5.0

Make sure env variable AIRFLOW_HOME is pointing to right location

Thanks all for sharing

Answer (score -1):

I added `sudo` and it actually worked just fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines before posting answers or questions. It's pointless to give the same answer as others did before you and keep in mind that answers can be treated as comments.

Answer (score -2):

I got the same error today and a `sudo` did the trick to me