# Airflow installation throwing error No module named 'airflow.www' Running Airflow locally

Tags: airflow

I'm installing airflow locally using [below way](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html)

```
    export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow

AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.1.3
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
# For example: 3.6
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"
# For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.1.3/constraints-3.8.txt
pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"

# initialize the database
airflow db init
#user creation
airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname test \
    --lastname test \
    --role Admin \
    --email test@superhero.org
```

and then when I'm going to start airflow webserver using

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

getting error message

## Error: No module named 'airflow.www'

any help will be appreciate

Comment: I guess the installation did not succeed. You should share results of your installation because probably error is there/

Comment: And maybe you had airflow 1.10 installed before - if so - remove it and start with a clean virtualenv

Comment: @JarekPotiuk i tried AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.1.3 this version and it installed successfully

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. This error has something to do with the fact that Airflow is not importing your package correctly assuming you did install the package correctly. If you have a folder named "airflow" in your project directory (this was what happened to me), and you are executing the command airflow webserver --port 8080 within the project directory, this will confuse Airflow to import from the wrong directory and return this error even though you have the Airflow package installed. I had to just rename the folder to airflow_dag and it worked. Initially I tried the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583633/how-to-resolve-error-no-module-named-airflow-www-while-starting-airflow-web) and it didn't work for me, as in my case, it has nothing to do with gunicorn.